# How to ensure list contains unique elements?

Tags: python, list

I have a class containing a list of strings.  Say:

```
ClassName:
 - list_of_strings
```

I need to enforce that this list of strings contains unique elements.  Unfortunately, I can't change this list_of_strings to another type, like a set.

In the `addToList(str_to_add)` function, I want to guarantee string uniqueness.  How can I best do this?  Would it be practical to add the string being added to the list, convert to a set, then back to a list, and then reassign that to the object?

Here's the method I need to update:

```
def addToList(self, str_to_add):
    self.list_of_strings.append(str_to_add)
```

Thanks!

Comment: *Why* can't you use a set?  It seems to be the appropriate data type here.

Comment: Can the list be in sorted order? If so, then you can use a binary search. Otherwise, you are stuck with some linear-order algorithm, so converting to a set may just be the easiest thing if absolute speed isn't a requirement.

Comment: Presumably he wants to preserve order, or there's already code in place that expects an ordered list rather than a set. An ordered set or unique list is a reasonable data type.

Comment: Converting back and forth to a set will be much less efficient than doing a linear search to see if the item already exists in the list. By stating that you can't change the data type you've boxed yourself into a corner.

Comment: @bnaul:  Of course are there valid reasons for this, but they are relevant for answering.

Comment: @Sven Marnach: I can't use a set because they're Model classes for Google's App Engine, which has a db.ListProperty() but not a db.SetProperty().

Comment: @Cuga:  I don't know anything about GAE, so could you please explain this a bit further?  Do you need to pass your container to a function expecting a list?  Or do you need a container with some fixed interface?  (I'm asking this questions because I suspect there is a better solution.)

Comment: GAE's model classes are restricted to certain types: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html Unfortunately, a 'set' is not one of them so there doesn't appear to be any way of automatically storing a set.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
def addToList(self, str_to_add):
    if str_to_add not in self.list_of_strings:
        self.list_of_strings.append(str_to_add)
```

Comment: Ahh... you're right and this is correct for the problem I described.  Embarassingly, I just realized I described my problem wrong and the issue I'm having is entirely different.

Answer (score 4):

Either check for the presence of the string in the list with `in`, or use a `set` in parallel that you can check and add to.

Comment: The parallel set is an interesting idea.

Comment: This one is probably more efficient in terms of the the lookups, especially if the list is large.

Answer (score 1):

You indeed could do the list-to-set-to-list operation you described, but you could also use the `in` operator to check if the element is already in the list before appending it.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to do this would be to create a hash set and iterate through the list, adding the elements to the set; a second iteration could be used to remove any duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps we can do like this:

def addToList(self, str_to_add):

```
try:
    self.list_of_strings.index(str_to_add)
except:
    self.list_of_strings.append(str_to_add)
```

Well, I don't know whether it's the same mechanism with if/else  yet.